# How can I let API gateway forward the path to down stream application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I build an API gateway in AWS and use `/{proxy+}` to forward all requests under the path `/` to my down stream ALB (ALB_ENDPOINT). But I found API gateway doesn't keep the path during forwarding. For example, if users requset `APIGATEAY_ENDPOINT/abc` to API gateway, it will forward it to `ALB_ENDPOINT/` instead of `ALB_ENDPOINT/abc`. It seems API gateway removes the path from the endpoint.

How can I make API gateway persists the path when it forwards it to downstream application?

Comment: you are using HTTP Api or REST Api ? we need to ensure that there is `/{proxy}` at the end of the Endpoint URL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we define a /{proxy+} like this:

[image]

`proxy` will be the path parameter of the request and entire path can be appended to integration endpoint by simply adding /{proxy} at the end of the url and mapping that proxy from `method.request.path.proxy`

We need to add /{proxy} at the end of the endpoint url

[image]

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html) is the tutorial for HTTP Api

[image]