# AWS Gateway API partial path redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Lets illustrate a little bit, i using API Gateway as a reverse proxy for 2 sites hosted on diferent servers, the main pourpose is to put an wordpress in a path like /blog under my main domain, so i have:

- `site1.com`
- `myblog.com` (wordpress installed)
- a domain name like `myawesomedomain.com`

I have an route(in gateway api) like `/blog/{proxy+}` that sends everything to `myblog.com`, now to the problem.

If i puth this URL `myawesomedomain.com/blog/wp-content/assets/css/style.css` it got redirected to `myblog.com/blog/wp-content/assets/css/style.css` which lead to an 404 since `myblog.com/blog` dosent exists

So i would like to redirect like this

```
myawesomedomain.com/blog/wp-content/assets/css/style.css -> myblog.com/wp-content/assets/css/style.css
```

note the missing `/blog` path.

how could i achieve this?

Comment: can you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66594362/10186808) answer and confirm if you have configured similarly ? This shouldn't happen, only the the path within the path parameter {proxy} should be appended to myblog.com

Comment: you are awsome, thanks a lot, dont realize i could replace only the {proxy+} path part, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments.

`proxy` will be the path parameter of the request and entire path can be appended to integration endpoint by simply adding /{proxy} at the end of the url and mapping that `proxy` variable value from method.request.path.proxy.

and any resource paths above the resource `{proxy}` will be automatically ignored.

Details on how to add proxy parameters are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66594362/10186808) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html)